# WSUS Too many "not applicable" updates. Is this normal?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I have just implemented WSUS in production for the first time.
Everything is working fine, but the info reported by the Update Service Manager is a bit unintuitive.

When i check on a computers status it checks for "installed/not applicable", which in our case allways shows like 90+k updates as seen here:

[image]

So when i try to check how many % of updates are installed on a computer it allways says 99% (since 99.9 of them are not applicable) like so:

[image]

Is this normal?
Is there any way to remove the "or not applicable" part of the criteria for compliance?

Running WSUS version 10.0.10514.4 on a server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woops, had accidentally approved all updates through an auto approve rule...
Unapproved unused updates and now its much better.

Comment: That's happened to all of us! Don't forget to [accept your own answer](https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Even better than accepting your own answer is explaining how you fixed it. This answer doesn't help anyone who shows up and doesn't already know how to do that, which is why I'm here.